# Kaplansky's theorem and Axiom of choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice, projective-modules, modules, ra.rings-and-algebras

Kaplansky in his paper titled by [**Projective Modules**](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970252?uid=3738280&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21101201021821) gave an important and essential theorem as follow:

**Theorem**: Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module which is a direct sum of (any number of) countably generated $R$-modules. Then any direct summand of $M$ is likewise a direct sum of countably generated $R$-modules.

But if you could take a look to the pattern of his proof, he applied the well ordering Theorem for proving it.

I am thinking about the relation of his proof with the **well ordering theorem**. More precisely I am thinking about the answer of the following question:

> Question: Is the Kaplansky theorem equivalent with the Axiom of Choice or it can be proved with the weaker axiom (i.e.boolean prime ideal theorem)?